# Compiling C++ project from powershell is not working

Tags: c++, powershell, makefile

I am programming a chess engine with 2 friends and it is getting very strong (above 3000 Elo).
We have written the code in C++ and compile using make. For some reason the normal installer for MinGW did not do what it was supposed to so I went with msys2 and installed all the requires packages using msys2.

I am not familiar with compiling C++ under windows and here is the problem:

When I compile the program using the Git Bash or powershell, it compiles nicely (except for a few warnings) using: `make native`

[image]

The issue is the way I need to execute the program:

- It does not work if I run using powershell or cmd
- It does not work if I double click it (see the error message below)
- It does only work if invoked from a bash

[image]

If you are not familiar with german, this is a rough translation:

```
The procedure entry point "..." was not found in the DLL "..."
```

---

We have provided a makefile which can build different versions (native, release (for multiple hardwares)). Running a non-native version like `Koivisto_3.9-x64-windows-popcnt-avx.exe` does run  by simply double clicking it.

Also the file sizes are very different:

- native: `600kb`
- non-native: `3100kb`

The entire project is on github: [Koivisto Chess Engine](https://github.com/Luecx/Koivisto)

And the makefile can be found here: [Makefile](https://github.com/Luecx/Koivisto/blob/master/src_files/makefile)

---

I wonder why there seems to be that difference and why the native version only runs within a bash. I am very happy if someone could explain this behaviour to me and potentially even tell me a way to fix this.

I am very happy for any advice!

Greetings,
Finn

Comment: Please copy-paste text *as text* into your question. Not only code, but also error messages. And of course the code (in the form of a [mcve]) that creates those errors, with comments on the lines with the errors.

Comment: The only error message that pops up has been pasted as an image.

Comment: "native" means "depends on this specific environment", so it shallowly links to runtime dependencies found in the environment where it was compiled, resulting in a way smaller file - those dependencies can't be found _outside_ the environment (the `PATH` env variable in your `bash` shell will be different from Explorer for example), which is why it fails to load. This is all expected behavior as far as I can tell

Comment: So would I need to copy the path from my bash to my powershell path?

Comment: According to that, it should work if I compile using powershell and also try to execute it within the powershell which does not work